# How to print strings matching a pattern with grep?

Tags: grep

I want to get a list of strings matching the following pattern:

```
CLASS_NAME:"*"
```

where `*` represents any number of characters.

I tried:

```
grep -o CLASS_NAME:\".*\" script.js
```

and

```
grep -o CLASS_NAME:\"*\" script.js
```

The first case returns the entire line after the matched string while the second case terminates at the first `"`. How can I get it to return just the matched string?

Comment: `grep -o 'CLASS_NAME:".*"' script.js`

Comment: @mikeserv, nope, it doesn't work. Got same result as my first case.

Comment: Is there actually another quote mark on the same line? And you definitely used the single'quotes? Cause I just tested it and it worked... Maybe you just don't want spaces? `grep -o 'CLASS_NAME:[^ ]*'`

Comment: Ah, you are right. There are more than two quotation marks on the single line. That's why it is returning more than what I required. I need to extract all class names from the minified script. Anyway to prevent that?

Comment: Yeah - you have to narrow acceptable output. What is definitely the very next character that you DON'T want to see...?

Comment: I found that those matching more has `}` after the quotation mark. Maybe I can exclude that?

Comment: This is what you do: `grep -o 'CLASS_NAME:"[^"]*"' script.js` - that'll ensure you only match to the very next double-quote and nothing more.

Comment: Fantastic! Hey, why don't you put it down as an answer. I am more than willing to give you the 25 points you deserve :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I guess your problem was that multiple-quote marks per line were pulling in more than you wanted because regex is inherently greedy - it will always match as much as possible if it can.

So the solution is to ensure you only match between the two double-quote marks, like:

```
grep -o 'CLASS_NAME:"[^"]*"' script.js
```